# Seaborn 'pairplot' function ends with an error " 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute '_make_twin_axes' "

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have MacOsX, 10.9.5, Mavericks. Current software versions:

- Python 2.7
- Matplotlib 1.4.3
- IPython 2.4.1
- Seaborn 0.6.0 (the same problem on 0.7.0.dev0)

When I try to call the `seaborn.pairplot` function, it ends up with the same error. Example:

```
>>> import seaborn as sns
>>> iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")
>>> g = sns.pairplot(iris)
```

Result:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-a5463baed793> in <module>()
----> 1 g = sns.pairplot(iris)

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/seaborn/linearmodels.pyc in pairplot(data, hue, hue_order, palette, vars, x_vars, y_vars, kind, diag_kind, markers, size, aspect, dropna, plot_kws, diag_kws, grid_kws)
   1600     if grid.square_grid:
   1601         if diag_kind == "hist":
-> 1602             grid.map_diag(plt.hist, **diag_kws)
   1603         elif diag_kind == "kde":
   1604             diag_kws["legend"] = False

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/seaborn/axisgrid.pyc in map_diag(self, func, **kwargs)
   1303                                                  frameon=False)
   1304                 else:
-> 1305                     diag_ax = ax._make_twin_axes(sharex=ax, frameon=False)
   1306                 diag_ax.set_axis_off()
   1307                 diag_axes.append(diag_ax)

AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute '_make_twin_axes'
```

I reinstalled `numpy` and `matplotlib` with  `easy_install`, re-installed `seaborn`, and also installed development version of seaborn. Neither helped, I have the same error with each configuration set. Googling on the question also didn't help, seems that I'm the only one having such a problem.

Perhaps, the private member `_make_twin_axes` was deprecated or changed.

UPD:

1. downgrading to `matplotlib==1.4.2` didn't help.
2. downgrading to `seaborn==0.4.0` didn't help.
3. downgrading to `matplotlib==1.3.1` didn't help.

After downgrading I'm not sure that the bug is in `seaborn` or `matplotlib`, but now I have no ideas, what can be done.

Comment: Are you sure the python environment you're installing packages into is the same one you're using when you're running the code? It's possible `easy_install` and `python` (or `ipython`, however you're using it) are looking at different library directories.

Comment: Actually, you are right, because my python uses another version of matplotlib __version__ = 1.1.1, and path is also different. It seems that using virtualenv will be correct solution, I'll write a bit later about the results. I thought, however, that executing ``sudo pip install matplotlib`` installs the library globally on the whole system and it would replace the old one, but I felt that it was a bad idea.

Comment: The `virtualenv` solved the problem, however, I don't understand yet, why ordinary installation `sudo pip install matplotlib` and `sudo easy_install --upgrade matplotlib` did not change my matplotlib version inside the python (I believed it should, by default). At first I tried to know version via `pip show matplotlib` and this displayed upgraded one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is for MacOS X there is a built-in Python. If you type (in `bash` or `zsh`)

```
which python
```

and receive

```
/usr/bin/python
```

Then you are probably using the system built-in Python.

The next step is to obtain the order, in which Python imports its packages. We run `python`, and then

```
import sys
sys.path
```

Usually the folder with built-in packages (non-upgradable)

```
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python'
```

is standing before the folder with user-installed packages

```
'/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/'
```

So you can't import new `matplotlib` unless you change the order of loading the packages or import your matplotlib (or numpy, whatever) directly from the folder, where it is installed. Note that I could not uninstall the 1.1.1 matplotlib version.

Another solution is to keep two versions of python installed. This way is recommended by official sources.

My solution was a bit of hardcore, this is not the best one, but hopefully, nothing has gone wrong since then. I deleted the folder `matplotlib` from `Extras`, i.e. the old 1.1.1 version, and then installed new version from git sources. I can recommend only the above mentioned solutions :)